# Adobe edge website: Calling a javascript function on form submit

Tags: javascript, form-submit, adobe-edge

I am trying to help out a stranded website owner. The developer seems to have used Adobe Edge which I am not familiar with. The issue is that the form on the home page of http://voicejared.com/ intends to call submitBtn.click (in index_edgeActions.js) but there seems to be one missing link.

Can anybody please help?

Comment: There form works fine, I fill it out and press submit and it works.

Comment: And sendEmail.php handles sending it